# My MoviePlayer doesn't respond to function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios4

I am facing problem of memory leak and other MoviePlayer new initiation as my MoviePlayer doesn't respond to function, in which I am releasing that player on my done button.

```
(void) playMovieAtURL
{

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
    mpViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];

    [mpViewController.view setCenter:self.view.center];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:mpViewController]; 

} 


    // When the movie is done,release the controller. (Doesn't come in it.)
-(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification 
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[aNotification object]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                  object:theMovie]; 

    // Release the movie instance created in playMovieAtURL
    [theMovie release]; 
}
```

Comment: are you release your movie player

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's your case, but this is what documentation says about MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification:

> This notification is not sent in cases
>   where the movie player is displaying
>   in fullscreen mode and the user taps
>   the Done button. In that instance, the
>   Done button causes movie playback to
>   pause while the player transitions out
>   of fullscreen mode. If you want to
>   detect this scenario in your code, you
>   should monitor other notifications
>   such as
>   MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification.

It seems  that MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is called just when the movie stops by itself.
If you are using the Done button, you should use MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it by passing nil and now it is returning me callbacks but still the movie won't releases, I will try ur suggestion also. Anyways my new code

```
-(void) playMovieAtURL
{

MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
mpViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];

[mpViewController.view setCenter:self.view.center];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) 
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
 object:nil]; 

} 

// When the movie is done,release the controller. 
-(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification 
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[aNotification object]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
        object:nil]; 

    // Release the movie instance created in playMovieAtURL
    [theMovie release]; 
}
```